# generating features and labels using iterator in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset with features and labels. I want to generate 3 things out of it :

```
x,y,lb = train_data
```

my `train_data`has features and labels from indexes lets say `0 to 100`. I want `x`to have `feature` samples from `1 to 100`, `y` should have `labels`from `0 to 99` and `lb` should have the label at index `100`.

Further I would like to do this in sliding batches using iterator. Currently I have the following code which generates `x` from `0 to 100`and `y` from `0 to 100`. And the next batch starts from `x : 1 to 101`and `y:1 to 101` and so on.

```
features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,None],name="input_features")
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1],name = "input_labels")

iterator = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
           .apply(sliding.sliding_window_batch(timestep=100, stride=1))
           .batch(10)
           .make_initializable_iterator()
           )
next_element = iterator.get_next(name="batch")
init_op = iterator.initializer
saveable = tf.contrib.data.make_saveable_from_iterator(iterator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have windows of 101 elements and slice accordingly later:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import sliding

features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1000, 10],name="input_features")
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1000, 1],name = "input_labels")
iterator = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
           .apply(sliding.sliding_window_batch(window_size=101, window_shift=1))
           .batch(10)
           .make_initializable_iterator()
           )
x_it, y_it = iterator.get_next(name="batch")
x, y, lb = x_it[:, 1:], y_it[:, :-1], y_it[:, -1]
init_op = iterator.initializer
saveable = tf.contrib.data.make_saveable_from_iterator(iterator)
```

Comment: damn this was pretty easy. never occurred to me that i could slice later. thanks a lot